# Variable substitution into strings

Tags: .net, vb.net

Can I do something like `"%s said %s blah.", $name, $blah;` in VB.NET?

It's getting painful writing `name & "said" & blah & "blah"`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yup, use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx):

```
Dim newString As String = String.Format("{0} said {1} blah.", name, blah)
```

Answer (score 31):

In VB.NET 14 (for VS2015), you can use [string interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160(v=vs.140).aspx):

```
Dim newString As String = $"{name} said {blah} blah."
```

Comment: Can anyone think of why this might *not* be an improvement?  I want to tell my team that this is an unequivocal improvement, but want to be sure I'm not missing something before claiming so.

Comment: @ardave If you've got a chance of needing internationalisation later, you'll need to revert to the `String.Format` call so the format string can become a variable or function to retrieve from a resource file, etc.

Comment: For the internationalization, you could also use an helper function that would require less modification to the code as [explained here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/c-6-string-interpolation-is-not-a-templating-engine-and-it-s-not-the-new-string-format):

`public string Format(FormattableString fs)
{
    // Get localized version of the default language string:
    var localFormat = GetLocalized(fs.Format);
    // Feed the resulting format string into String.Format:
    return String.Format(localFormat, fs.GetArguments());
}`

Comment: @user74754 I just discovered this writing in C#.NET in VS2017 (having been primarily a VB.NET/VS2013 guy for a long time) and I love it. Better than `String.Format` or `"this" &/+ "that"` IMO. I'm adopting it wholesale.